# how to deal with multiple buttons in sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I have 21 togglebuttons and was wondering how to save state of each individual one using sharedpreferences?

i've tried with this:

```
button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PREFS_NAME, true));
```

but how to make it store values for all buttons and can i do it in PREFS_NAME for all of them?

ok so i created xml file with those buttons:

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:textOff="1"
        android:textOn="*"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/tB1" />
```

and activity with this code:

```
 int [] viewIds = new int [] {R.id.tB1, R.id.tB2, ...
 String [] stringIds = new String [] {"R.id.tB1" ...
 ToggleButton button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.randd_screen);

    for(int i =0; i<viewIds.length;i++)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "inside loop");
        Log.d(TAG, "Run no.:" + i);
        button =(ToggleButton)findViewById(viewIds[i]);

        Log.d(TAG, "button = " + button);
        Log.d(TAG, "from stringIds[i] " + stringIds[i]);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
        button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(Integer.toString(viewIds[i]), false));

    }
}
```

now, how to create onClick method which would update each button value as well as save and load it?

**Update 2**

so that how my activity look like now but it does not preserve checked buttons. am i missing something or done something wrong?

```
int [] viewIds = new int [] {R.id.tB1, R.id.tB2, ...
String [] stringIds = new String [] {"R.id.tB1", ...

ToggleButton button;


}

    button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tB2);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(stringIds[1], true));

}


ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.d(TAG, "in onCheckChanged()");
        int [] viewIds = new int[2];
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < viewIds.length; index++) {
            if (v.getId() == viewIds[index]) {
                getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean(stringIds[index], isChecked)
                        .apply();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.randd_screen);


    for(int i =0; i<viewIds.length;i++)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "inside loop");
        Log.d(TAG, "Run no.:" + i);
        button =(ToggleButton)findViewById(viewIds[i]);

        Log.d(TAG, "button = " + button);
        Log.d(TAG, "from stringIds[i] " + stringIds[i]);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
        button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(stringIds[i], false));

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);



    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store state for all of them.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PREFS_BUTTON1, true));

button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PREFS_BUTTON2, true));

button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
button.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PREFS_BUTTON3, true));

//...
```

You could make it much cleaner by implementing a list of IDs and their preference key. You could then loop through them, setting buttons as required.

### Updated Question

Do *not* use the generated integer resource as a `SharedPreferences` identifier `Integer.toString(viewIds[i])`. You creating a String array for that purpose. Use that instead `stringIds[i]`.

You can create a listener and apply the same listener to every ToggleButton. In that listener you check which button recieved the call and set the appropriate preference.

```
ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < viewIds.length; index++) {
            if (v.getId() == viewIds[index]) {
                getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean(stringIds[index], isChecked)
                        .apply();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer, now, does it mean i need to create 21 PREFS_NAME String objects? is there any way of storing all buttons state in one file?

Comment: They are stored in one file, in this example `PREFS_NAME` is the identifier for the file that is stored. The individual `PREFS_BUTTON1` identifiers are for each button, and are stored in the `PREFS_NAME` preference file.

Comment: question now is how to create onClick()  method to handle different state of buttons and how to save and load it state...

Comment: i am quite new to android so excuse me basic question but.. how to apply this listener to buttons?

Comment: Try investigating a little bit before asking. You will be able to resolve most things quick a [quickly crafted search query](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android+togglebutton+OnCheckedChangeListener).

Comment: thanks Knossos, only thing to be changed is to comment out this line `int [] viewIds = new int[2];` as it is declared above the listener.

Comment: Oops - I left that in by mistake. I wrote that to avoid compile errors when I wrote the example. I will edit it out.

Comment: on those which are set as true i want to perform some action, how to get list of those? - can you help?

Comment: Rather than making new questions here, Stack Overflow works better as a Q&A system if you make a new question with the relevant code snippets to support it. Otherwise we aren't helping future readers. Feel free to link me to the new question.

Comment: sorry, i am so new to this, how to link user to question?

Comment: Simply make the question, click the share button and you can post that link in a comment here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844475/getting-list-of-values-from-sharedprefsrences